# @PathVariable and @RequestParam and Object as method argument

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I just started to work with Spring MVC and in my project have some code:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/users/in_group", method = RequestMethod.GET)
@ResponseBody
public List<UserInfo> getUsersInGroup(@RequestParam Department department) {

    return UserUtil.convertUsers(group.getUsers());
}
```

and

```
public String formBuilderPage(@PathVariable("department") Department department, Model model){
// some code
}
```

As I've read in Spring reference, `@PathVariable` must be either String or primitive, and this rules related to `@RequestParam`. So my question: how Spring creates this objects, from what context Spting gives it, and how can I make it to work in future? Thanks!

Comment: I didn't really undetstood your question.. How spring convert this Objects backstage?
@Request parameter can be non primitive.. In your example we can see it.. So i am not sure i understand :)

Comment: what do you mean by _how can I make it to work in future?_

Comment: This is a really badly structured set of questions that really should be rewritten with specifics to help us provide answer